# Sort a dropdown list with optgroups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with a lot of items that I'd like to have in alphabetical order, if it makes a difference, the dropdown uses optgroups.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<optgroup label="Fruits">
<option>Banana</option>
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Orange</option>
<option>Avocado</option>
</optgroup>
```

How would I make it so that it would show them in alphabetical order for each optgroup? In the example above it order would be Apple, Avocado, Banana, Orange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sort()`

```js
$('optgroup[label="Fruits"] option').sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).text() > $(b).text();
}).appendTo('optgroup[label="Fruits"]');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<optgroup label="Fruits">
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Avocado</option>
</optgroup>
```